# php-move_upload_file file size issue

Tags: php

I have a problem while moving a file which is uploaded. While moving the files that are more than 2MB are not moving to my desired location. What should i do to make the files that have size upto 2GB move to a specific location while uploading?

Comment: what have u tried? paste your code..

Comment: have you specified any file size limit?

Comment: I told it is allowing only 2MB. I need 2GB. Please read the question

Comment: you know how long a http 2GB file transfer would take? http is not the protocol for this. and don't get snippy with peole trying to help. hope you have some serous resources hosting this

Comment: 2GB is an exceptional case.files that will be uploaded will only be upto 10Mb in normal case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change these values in your php ini

```
max_execution_time 36000
max_input_time 60
upload_max_filesize 2000M
post_max_size 2000M
```

You can do it using .htaccess and in your php code using `ini_set("max_execution_time",3600);`

Comment: is 16mb the maximum i can set??

Comment: No, I guess you can set any value but the uploading file size should be less than that.

Answer (score 0):

Make change to your php.ini file configuration where  `upload_max_filesize = 2M` . Simply change its value to somewhat bigger

Comment: I tried it. Just upload_max_filesize value didn't wasn't good..Any more values i need to change?

Comment: I use 64M which is always good for me. And don't forget to increase the maximum execution time to more than 30 seconds. See @Prasanth Bendra's answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
ini_set('post_max_size', '2048M');
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '2048M');
and you may need to look at setting php's memory limit up also:
ini_set('memory_limit', '128M');
```

Comment: is this only that i need to add or anything else?

Comment: you will need to set max execution time(in seconds) like Prasanth said above to accommodate such large files.
`ini_set('max_execution_time', 36000);`

Answer (score 0):

Be default the maximum upload size is set to 2M in the php.ini file, you need to change it to a greater value.

Make changes to the following variables in php.ini file :

```
upload_max_filesize
post_max_size
```

Set these to the values you desire.

Note : post_max_size value must be greater than upload_max_filesize

Comment: for your reference http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.common-pitfalls.php

Answer (score 0):

```
note: php.ini file max execution time change 

if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

    if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
      }
    }
```